# Handling compound primary keys in NHibernate event listeners

Tags: database, nhibernate, event-handling, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to extract the primary key property name and value of the original entity from within an NHibernate event listener and I want it to be able to handle compound primary keys.

The problem I'm having is that in my event handler, when dealing with a compound primary key, the `Id` property of the event that gets fired seems to get bound to the **entire** original entity:

[image: Compound primary key getting bound to original entity]

How do I get at the original ID property names and corresponding values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following code for components:

```
if (@event.Persister.IdentifierType.IsComponentType)
{
    var componentType = (IAbstractComponentType) @event.Persister.IdentifierType;
    var values = componentType.GetPropertyValues(@event.Id);
    var propertyNames = componentType.PropertyNames;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"PropertyName: {propertyNames[i]}, Value: {values[i]}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (@event.Persister.IdentifierType is NHibernate.Type.EmbeddedComponentType identifierType)
{
    // This entity has a composite primary key.

    foreach (var propertyName in identifierType.PropertyNames)
    {
        // Because we only have the name of the property we have to use reflection to get
        // the corresponding value.
        object propertyValue = @event.Id.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(entityId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `identifierType.GetPropertyValues(@event.Id, session)` instead of reflection

Comment: @RomanArtiukhin That doesn't give me an explicit mapping between property names and values, just a collection of values.

Comment: Order is the same  for `identifier.PropetyNames` and `identifierType.GetPropertyValues`. So you can map between them easily by index